# Recovering original json string incorrectly encoded using Buffer.from(..., "base64")

Tags: javascript, json, encoding, base64, buffer

I uploaded some data that was incorrectly encoded. I took a JSON string (`data`) and passed it into the `Buffer.from(data, "base64")`. So `Buffer.from` expected a Base64 string but received a UTF-8 string. And that buffer was then uploaded to S3.
When I downloaded the JSON files I was expecting a JSON string and instead got stuff that looked like this:

```
�ǫ�.�Ɲ�)��ę����h�*��a���r��w(c˰�� W�G}��n�^�'2��V�߃r)���H�ץ1�I}t�^�
i��l�����ߢ�L��G�y�(
����m4�&�j���;뫬z���x���\�^�
```

Code to recreate the error:

```
const data = {
  userGroups: '["admin"]',
  userEmail: "hodor@iron-throne.com",
  id: "yhjy7C5pCBX_kd9xckVbt",
  device:
    "Mozilla/3.4 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/533.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/152.0.0.0 Safari/5647.66",
  userCognitoId: "c75de28",
};

const recreateFileCorruption = () => {
  const jsonPrettyString = JSON.stringify(data);

  const body = new Buffer.from(jsonPrettyString, "base64");
  return body;
};

const runTest = () => {
  const data = recreateFileCorruption();
  console.log("Broken data string:", data.toString());
  console.log("Somewhat decoded string", Buffer.from(data.toString("base64"), "utf-8").toString());
};
```

Running the `runTest` function outputs this to the terminal:

```
Broken data string: �ǫ�.�Ɲ�)��ę����h�*��a���r��w(c˰�� W�G}��n�^�'2��V�߃r)���H�ץ1�I}t�^�
i��l�����ߢ�L��G�y�(
����m4�&�j���;뫬z���x���\�^�
```

Is there any way to recover the original JSON string? Or is that data lost forever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's lost.

I checked the length with

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data).length);
```

and got 249 characters. If you have 249 Base64 characters and each one encodes 6 bits, you would expect a resulting buffer of 249*6/8 = 186 bytes.

But the actual size of the data buffer after this

```
const data = recreateFileCorruption();
console.log(data.length)
```

is only 139 bytes.
That is because

```
new Buffer.from(jsonPrettyString, "base64");
```

just skips every non-Base64 character, and a JSON-string is full of them, e.g. `{}":,[]` and others. `Buffer.from` is even so nice to accept the original Base64 characters as well as the Base64URL variant ("-" as a substitute for "+" and "_" for "/").

It's should be no surprise that the non-Base64 characters are skipped, because there is no 6-bit value associated with them and therefore a decoder can't handle them. The only alternative here would be to raise an exception.

I also removed all non-Base64 characters manually from the string and got a length of 186 characters which after decoding will result in a Buffer of 139 bytes. Same as we saw above.

So

```
 console.log("Somewhat decoded string", Buffer.from(data.toString("base64"), "utf-8").toString());
```

> Somewhat decoded string userGroupsadminuserEmailhodoriron+thronecomidyhjy7C5pCBX/kd9xckVbtdeviceMozilla/34MacintoshIntelMacOSX10/15/7AppleWebKit/53336KHTMLlikeGeckoChrome/152000Safari/564766userCognitoIdc75de2w==

is the best you can get, there's nothing else to restore at this point.